# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform with plugins architecture on .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#

I have an app that is a .NET Core 5 Web API "container".
I load dynamically multiples projets "Web API" as DLL.
Unfortunately, when a project is using EF to request a database, I got Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform error.

By adding Microsoft.Data.SqlClient as a nuget package on my web api container, it works but what I am not understanding is why my library, which should contains all the dll that is required by itself, cannot make a query into the database.

I have specified in the library csproj this settings :

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

and in the output folder I can see Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll

I run the project on my laptop, so no Azure involved.
Thanks for yor help !

Edit 1 :

I have seen this : https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#11-why-do-i-get-a-platformnotsupported-exception-when-my-application-hits-a-sqlclient-method
I wondering how I can indicate in my class library .NET 5 that this class lib will be used under a .NET 5 Web Api as it seems that despite targeting .NET 5 in both project, is not enough to get the appropriate dll...

Comment: The question is unclear because it describes non-existent behavior. A *library* is the single dll output. Not its dependencies. If you add a reference to a library, you don't get its dependencies. That happens only if you add a reference to a *project*. A NuGet package on the other hand contains all the dlls the package author wanted to include, and Package dependencies for anything else. `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` doesn't affect how DLL references are added at all. `a .NET Core 5 Web API "container"` what does that mean? A Docker container? A Solution file? A folder?

Comment: `By adding Microsoft.Data.SqlClient as a nuget package` do that then. *That's* the proper to use any NuGet package. Or create your own package and make sure it references the NuGet packages it needs, not the DLL files. `is not supported on this platform error` typically means you tried to load an x64 assembly in a x86 process or vice versa. `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` contains architecture specific files. I suspect you copied the wrong files to the deployment folder. Using the NuGet package will ensure the correct files are included when publishing